How to Convert Mesh to Curve but Using Face, instead of Edge
In short, I can convert any mesh into a Curve but it uses Edges. Is there any way to make a Curve but in the middle of the face ??
I want to use this method to create a Street Curve from Street Meshes that I downloaded from the Internet.

There is the option to add a loop, which is by default in the middle of the faces:

Then remove all the other segments (or duplicate and separate the mid line) and convert to curve:


The road that I downloaded is not in that perfect rectangular shape, they have many random connects between vertex, so It not working

Then maybe share a screenshot or a file so that we can understand your precise request. You can edit your question to do so.
